# Prepaid SIM card for data in Italy

Tags: cellphones, data-plans, roaming, alps

I am looking for a (local) pre-paid data SIM card for my trip to Italy. What matters the most is a price for GB of data only, I don't really need voice calls. Coverage in the Alps should be decent too. I guess the local SIM still gives me the best value in comparison to EU-regulated data roaming charges.